# Theming of KDE apps with Gnome DE

Tags: kde, gnome3, theme

I'm using Gnome 3 on Arch Linux but I use some KDE applications like Okular.

I would like to make Okular and other KDE applications use a dark theme to match the one I'm using in Gnome.

I noticed that there is a `~/.kde4` folder in home.

How do I go about it?

Comment: I believe this is what you were looking for?
[Make KDE Applications Look Native In GNOME (With Ubuntu Ambiance Style)](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/04/make-kde-applications-look-native-in.html).